# Settings while debugging for battery optimization

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, battery-life

I just got my new LG G2 4.4.2 and since I will debug in it a lot, I want to know what settings should I use in order to harm less my battery. While in debug mode, I have 5 options:

1. Charge phone
2. Media sync (MTP)
3. Tethering
4. LG software
5. Send images (PTP)

Which one should I choose for less battery consumption? Also any other setting that could boost my battery life?

Thanks

Comment: But your device must be connected via USB, and in 1,2,5, which by far are found in most of the android devices, the device charges itself while it gets used via one of these three modes. Since its charging, albeit slow in 2 and 5, why worry for battery consumption I ask?

Comment: I don't know what's the "damage" of the battery while charging (even on "slow" mode). But since my phone will be most of the time debugging, I want these settings to be the best possible.